# Mock framework for easy creation of inline mocks

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, powermock, easymock

Does any of the popular java mocking libraries support inline creation of partial mocks?

Something like:

```
 Foo fooMock = make(mock(Foo.class).returning("val1").from().method1());
    // or even
 Foo fooMock = PartialMock.of(Foo.class, new Mock<Foo>() {
         @Override
         String method1() { return "value"; }
 });
```

Where Foo looks like:

```
 interface Foo() {
     String method1();
     String method2();
    ....
 }
```

The closest I could find in my search were [hadoop's mockmaker](https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/classes/org.apache.hadoop.test.MockitoMaker)
and
[a StubBuilder class in the wild](http://www.javased.com/index.php?source_dir=hippo-rijkshuisstijl-archetype/src/main/resources/archetype-resources/site/src/test/java/beans/common/StubBuilder.java).

To be clear, I'm aware of mockito's method of creating the mock and defining the behavior afterwards with `Foo fooMock = mock(Foo.class);` followed by `when(mock.method1()).thenReturn("value")`. I'm wondering if there's a way to do this in single statement during mock creation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mockito to mock some methods but not others.

```
Stock stock = mock(Stock.class);
when(stock.getPrice()).thenReturn(100.00);    // Mock implementation
when(stock.getQuantity()).thenReturn(200);    // Mock implementation
when(stock.getValue()).thenCallRealMethod();  // Real implementation
```

Comment: My bad for not making this clearer, I was looking for a shorthand mechanism to do it at as part of mock instantiation, not afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is impossible. Let's look at your line of code:

```
PartialMock.of(Foo.class) // 1
           .withMethod()  // 2
           .method1()     // 3
           .thenReturn("value");
```

1. If `of` returns a `Foo` class, `withMethod` won't be there. So it needs to be a `FooBuilder`
2. If `withMethod` returns a `Foo` class, we have `method1` on it. But `method` won't return something with `thenReturn`. So we need a class with the same methods a `Foo` but with a different return type. A `FooMock` maybe. But this class doesn't exist at static compilation. We would need to make it appear like Lombok does. With compiler instrumentation
3. `method1` needs to return so `FooResult` now to have `thenReturn` on it

As you can see, that's a lot of really complex work for now much gain in terms of readability and easiness of use.

Also, we are you saying it's a partial mock? Looks like a normal mock to me.

Comment: The syntax needn't be exact and I am asking this since I have come across such a syntax a while back but can't remember which framework provided it. A more correct example would be :`PartialMock.of(Foo.class).suchThat(foo -> foo.method1()).returns("value").` Another realworld example I just found is Hadoop's MockitoMaker: https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/classes/org.apache.hadoop.test.MockitoMaker

Comment: Interesting. However, what I see from the example is that you can mock one thing. Then they use `when`. That said, it might be possible and this fluent way could prevent always adding static imports. If you are willing to PR EasyMock, go for it ;-)

Comment: The reason I asked this question is that I remember having seen this api (or a similar one) in either EasyMock, Powermock or some other library, but I can't remember which :(

Comment: I am not aware of EasyMock, Mockito, JMockit nor Spock doing that. Now sure what's left